# Changing file association via bat (specifically xml to chrome)

Tags: xml, google-chrome, batch-file, file-association

I've got a bat file that I pieced together to change .xml's default program to Chrome

```
ftype doc.Document="C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe"
assoc .xml=doc.Document
```

It appears to work.  When I check its associated program via the Set Associations interface it is correct.  However, when I try to open an xml, it simply launches chrome as if I had opened a new instance of chrome and does not open the xml.

At this point, if I manually change the associations via the Set Associations page to some other program and then back to Chrome again, it remains broken (launches a new instance of chrome) instead of behaving as if I had originally just used this interface (where it would open the xml in tabbed plain text).

So I guess my question is what is my bat missing?  If my bat isn't missing anything, then what can I do to return to the expected functionality?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Should add file to be transmitted to chrome as parameter (add %1 as parameter to chrome):

```
ftype doc.Document="C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe" "%%1"
```

This works for a batch file. Keep in mind that you need a single `%` for the command prompt.

Comment: Ah, thanks.  In a bat file that gets interpretted as the first param of the bat so I'm changing %1 to %%1 to escape the first %.

Comment: @LorenzMeyer The question asked was specifically for a bat.  The answer as now accepted is incorrect.  Why edit it back so it's incorrect for the question asked?  If anything it should say "This works for a bat.  Keep in mind that you need to not double the `%` for the command prompt."

Comment: Thanks, I thought maybe I was missing something 'cause I'm new 'round here.

Comment: Hey man, I just tried your code and it doesn't work. My batch only has this: `ftype doc.Document="C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe" "%%1"
assoc .pdf=doc.Document` and when I run as admin the .pdf viewer is not changed to chrome

Comment: @Linesofcode - run ftype and assoc commands under your admin user.